# Orchard Module Some Features need to be upgraded facebook.lite

Tags: orchardcms

I'm getting this message and cannot figure out whats wrong, here is a dump from my log file in APP_DATA. Anyone have any ideas how to clear?

```
2012-10-25 03:28:11,250 [5] Orchard.Data.Migration.AutomaticDataMigrations - Could not run migrations automatically on Facebook.Like
2012-10-25 03:32:25,938 [19] Orchard.Data.Migration.AutomaticDataMigrations - Could not run migrations automatically on Facebook.Like
2012-10-25 03:32:30,548 [19] Orchard.Exceptions.DefaultExceptionPolicy - An unexpected exception was caught
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The default schema does not exist.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Orchard.Data.Migration.Interpreters.DefaultDataMigrationInterpreter.RunPendingStatements() in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Migration\Interpreters\DefaultDataMigrationInterpreter.cs:line 347
   at Orchard.Data.Migration.Interpreters.DefaultDataMigrationInterpreter.Visit(CreateTableCommand command) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Migration\Interpreters\DefaultDataMigrationInterpreter.cs:line 93
   at Orchard.Data.Migration.Interpreters.AbstractDataMigrationInterpreter.Visit(ISchemaBuilderCommand command) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Migration\Interpreters\AbstractDataMigrationInterpreter.cs:line 14
   at Orchard.Data.Migration.Schema.SchemaBuilder.CreateTable(String name, Action`1 table) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Migration\Schema\SchemaBuilder.cs:line 19
   at Orchard.Indexing.Migrations.Create()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Orchard.Data.Migration.DataMigrationManager.Update(String feature) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Migration\DataMigrationManager.cs:line 96
   at Orchard.Data.Migration.DataMigrationCoordinator.Installing(Feature feature) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Migration\DataMigrationCoordinator.cs:line 26
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Orchard.Events.DefaultOrchardEventBus.TryInvokeMethod(IEventHandler eventHandler, Type interfaceType, String methodName, IDictionary`2 arguments, IEnumerable& returnValue) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Events\DefaultOrchardEventBus.cs:line 80
   at Orchard.Events.DefaultOrchardEventBus.TryInvoke(IEventHandler eventHandler, String interfaceName, String methodName, IDictionary`2 arguments, IEnumerable& returnValue) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Events\DefaultOrchardEventBus.cs:line 68
   at Orchard.Events.DefaultOrchardEventBus.TryNotifyHandler(IEventHandler eventHandler, String messageName, String interfaceName, String methodName, IDictionary`2 eventData, IEnumerable& returnValue) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Events\DefaultOrchardEventBus.cs:line 52
2012-10-25 03:32:34,923 [15] Orchard.Data.Migration.AutomaticDataMigrations - Could not run migrations automatically on Facebook.Like
2012-10-25 03:32:34,923 [15] Orchard.Data.Migration.AutomaticDataMigrations - Could not run migrations automatically on Orchard.Indexing
2012-10-25 03:32:35,376 [15] Orchard.Data.Migration.AutomaticDataMigrations - Could not run migrations automatically on Facebook.Like
2012-10-25 03:32:35,392 [15] Orchard.Data.Migration.AutomaticDataMigrations - Could not run migrations automatically on Orchard.Indexing
2012-10-25 03:36:39,173 [16] Orchard.Data.Migration.AutomaticDataMigrations - Could not run migrations automatically on Facebook.Like
2012-10-25 03:36:39,188 [16] Orchard.Data.Migration.AutomaticDataMigrations - Could not run migrations automatically on Orchard.Indexing
2012-10-25 03:36:57,690 [5] Orchard.Data.Migration.AutomaticDataMigrations - Could not run migrations automatically on Facebook.Like
2012-10-25 03:36:57,705 [5] Orchard.Data.Migration.AutomaticDataMigrations - Could not run migrations automatically on Orchard.Indexing
2012-10-25 03:39:38,121 [16] NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Could not execute query: INSERT INTO dbo_Orchard_Indexing_IndexingTaskRecord (Action, CreatedUtc, ContentItemRecord_id) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo_Orchard_Indexing_IndexingTaskRecord'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
2012-10-25 03:39:38,168 [16] NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter - Invalid object name 'dbo_Orchard_Indexing_IndexingTaskRecord'.
2012-10-25 03:39:38,168 [16] Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager - GenericADOException thrown from IContentHandler by Orchard.Indexing.Handlers.CreateIndexingTaskHandler
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert: [Orchard.Indexing.Models.IndexingTaskRecord][SQL: INSERT INTO dbo_Orchard_Indexing_IndexingTaskRecord (Action, CreatedUtc, ContentItemRecord_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo_Orchard_Indexing_IndexingTaskRecord'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
   at NHibernate.Id.IdentityGenerator.InsertSelectDelegate.ExecuteAndExtract(IDbCommand insert, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.Execute()
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrReplicate(Object entity, EntityKey key, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSave(Object entity, Object id, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj)
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Create(T entity) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:line 96
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Orchard.Data.IRepository<T>.Create(T entity) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:line 36
   at Orchard.Indexing.Services.IndexingTaskManager.CreateTask(ContentItem contentItem, Int32 action)
   at Orchard.Indexing.Services.IndexingTaskManager.CreateUpdateIndexTask(ContentItem contentItem)
   at Orchard.Indexing.Handlers.CreateIndexingTaskHandler.CreateIndexingTask(PublishContentContext context, ContentPart part)
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.ContentHandler.InlineStorageFilter`1.Published(PublishContentContext context, TPart instance) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Handlers\ContentHandler.cs:line 156
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.StorageFilterBase`1.Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.IContentStorageFilter.Published(PublishContentContext context) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Handlers\StorageFilterBase.cs:line 80
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.ContentHandler.Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.IContentHandler.Published(PublishContentContext context) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Handlers\ContentHandler.cs:line 274
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.<>c__DisplayClass5c.<Create>b__59(IContentHandler handler) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:line 495
   at Orchard.InvokeExtensions.Invoke[TEvents](IEnumerable`1 events, Action`1 dispatch, ILogger logger) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\InvokeExtensions.cs:line 17
2012-10-25 03:39:38,387 [16] NHibernate.AssertionFailure - An AssertionFailure occurred - this may indicate a bug in NHibernate or in your custom types.
NHibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in Orchard.Indexing.Models.IndexingTaskRecord entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
2012-10-25 03:39:38,387 [16] NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl - DTC transaction prepre phase failed
NHibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in Orchard.Indexing.Models.IndexingTaskRecord entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.CheckId(Object obj, IEntityPersister persister, Object id, EntityMode entityMode)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.GetValues(Object entity, EntityEntry entry, EntityMode entityMode, Boolean mightBeDirty, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.OnFlushEntity(FlushEntityEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEntities(FlushEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEverythingToExecutions(FlushEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoNetWithDistrubtedTransactionFactory.DistributedTransactionContext.System.Transactions.IEnlistmentNotification.Prepare(PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment)
2012-10-25 03:42:01,520 [16] Orchard.Data.Migration.AutomaticDataMigrations - Could not run migrations automatically on Facebook.Like
2012-10-25 03:42:01,520 [16] Orchard.Data.Migration.AutomaticDataMigrations - Could not run migrations automatically on Orchard.Indexing
2012-10-25 03:42:01,973 [16] Orchard.Data.Migration.AutomaticDataMigrations - Could not run migrations automatically on Facebook.Like
2012-10-25 03:42:01,973 [16] Orchard.Data.Migration.AutomaticDataMigrations - Could not run migrations automatically on Orchard.Indexing
2012-10-25 03:55:10,140 [13] NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Could not execute query: INSERT INTO dbo_Orchard_Indexing_IndexingTaskRecord (Action, CreatedUtc, ContentItemRecord_id) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo_Orchard_Indexing_IndexingTaskRecord'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
2012-10-25 03:55:10,187 [13] NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter - Invalid object name 'dbo_Orchard_Indexing_IndexingTaskRecord'.
2012-10-25 03:55:10,187 [13] Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager - GenericADOException thrown from IContentHandler by Orchard.Indexing.Handlers.CreateIndexingTaskHandler
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert: [Orchard.Indexing.Models.IndexingTaskRecord][SQL: INSERT INTO dbo_Orchard_Indexing_IndexingTaskRecord (Action, CreatedUtc, ContentItemRecord_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo_Orchard_Indexing_IndexingTaskRecord'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
   at NHibernate.Id.IdentityGenerator.InsertSelectDelegate.ExecuteAndExtract(IDbCommand insert, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.Execute()
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrReplicate(Object entity, EntityKey key, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSave(Object entity, Object id, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj)
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Create(T entity) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:line 96
   at Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Orchard.Data.IRepository<T>.Create(T entity) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:line 36
   at Orchard.Indexing.Services.IndexingTaskManager.CreateTask(ContentItem contentItem, Int32 action)
   at Orchard.Indexing.Services.IndexingTaskManager.CreateUpdateIndexTask(ContentItem contentItem)
   at Orchard.Indexing.Handlers.CreateIndexingTaskHandler.CreateIndexingTask(PublishContentContext context, ContentPart part)
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.ContentHandler.InlineStorageFilter`1.Published(PublishContentContext context, TPart instance) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Handlers\ContentHandler.cs:line 156
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.StorageFilterBase`1.Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.IContentStorageFilter.Published(PublishContentContext context) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Handlers\StorageFilterBase.cs:line 80
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.ContentHandler.Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.IContentHandler.Published(PublishContentContext context) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Handlers\ContentHandler.cs:line 274
   at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager.<>c__DisplayClass5c.<Create>b__59(IContentHandler handler) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultContentManager.cs:line 495
   at Orchard.InvokeExtensions.Invoke[TEvents](IEnumerable`1 events, Action`1 dispatch, ILogger logger) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\InvokeExtensions.cs:line 17
2012-10-25 03:55:10,202 [13] NHibernate.AssertionFailure - An AssertionFailure occurred - this may indicate a bug in NHibernate or in your custom types.
NHibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in Orchard.Indexing.Models.IndexingTaskRecord entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
2012-10-25 03:55:10,202 [13] NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl - DTC transaction prepre phase failed
NHibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in Orchard.Indexing.Models.IndexingTaskRecord entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.CheckId(Object obj, IEntityPersister persister, Object id, EntityMode entityMode)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.GetValues(Object entity, EntityEntry entry, EntityMode entityMode, Boolean mightBeDirty, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.OnFlushEntity(FlushEntityEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEntities(FlushEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEverythingToExecutions(FlushEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoNetWithDistrubtedTransactionFactory.DistributedTransactionContext.System.Transactions.IEnlistmentNotification.Prepare(PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment)
2012-10-25 04:13:27,741 [8] NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Could not execute query: INSERT INTO dbo_Orchard_Indexing_IndexingTaskRecord (Action, CreatedUtc, ContentItemRecord_id) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo_Orchard_Indexing_IndexingTaskRecord'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
2012-10-25 04:13:27,757 [8] NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter - Invalid object name 'dbo_Orchard_Indexing_IndexingTaskRecord'.
2012-10-25 04:13:27,772 [8] Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultContentManager - GenericADOException thrown from IContentHandler by Orchard.Indexing.Handlers.CreateIndexingTaskHandler
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert: [Orchard.Indexing.Models.IndexingTaskRecord][SQL: INSERT INTO dbo_Orchard_Indexing_IndexingTaskRecord (Action, CreatedUtc, ContentItemRecord_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo_Orchard_Indexing_IndexingTaskRecord'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior,
```

..........more

Comment: It means that the migration of that module is crashing.

Comment: Thanks, any ideas how i can roll back and/or avoid this, cheers, j

Comment: You shouldn't need to: if there is an exception during a migration, that should roll back the transaction. Deleting the module folder should make things go back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it Folks, I had to change the SQL Connect String to be the user credentials for the main database user and not the new account I created. It appears that modules may use CODE FIRST to alter the schema of the Orchard database